# How to retrieve all unique (Year, Quarter) combinations from a list of dates?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This works as a charm to retrieve all unique (Year, Month) combinations from my table:

```
SELECT
  STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(TIMESTAMP_TO_USEC(Date), '%Y-%m') as month,
FROM
  [Table]
```

It returns 2016-05, 2016-06, 2016-07, etc

Want to do the same thing for (Year, Quarter) but have found nothing. Any tips? I know quarter is very tricky on sql. Thanks!

Comment: i am using google big query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine the QUARTER function with the YEAR function:

```
select concat(string(year(timestamp)),'-Q',string(quarter(timestamp))) as mquerter
from [table]
group by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/) (uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" under "Show Options" in the UI) you can do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t), EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM t)
FROM MyTable;
```

For example:

```
WITH MyTable AS (
  SELECT t
  FROM UNNEST([TIMESTAMP '2016-01-01',
               TIMESTAMP '2016-04-03',
               TIMESTAMP '2016-02-28',
               TIMESTAMP '2017-06-25']) AS t
)
SELECT DISTINCT
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t) AS year,
  EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM t) AS quarter
FROM MyTable;
+------+---------+
| year | quarter |
+------+---------+
| 2016 | 1       |
| 2016 | 2       |
| 2017 | 2       |
+------+---------+
```